# Why does BLE device works for some time even when I turn off the bluetooth and does Android BLE work on base of cache as well?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have two mobiles Moto g4 plus and Samsung.

Moto G4 - Nougat
Samsung - Marshmallow

I am working on a BLE app. What I have observed is on the samsung device, if I turn off the bluetooth my app immediately notifies me that I have lost the connection.Surprisingly on my Moto phone even if I turn down the bluetooth my app is still able to change the values in BLE device for considerable amount of time. I am trying to figure out why is it happening ? and if yes is this the desired way ? Or is their some cache in some phones which maintains connection with the already connected device for some amount of time ?

I have gone through this question

[android- ble device status shows connected for some seconds even after turning off the device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26434202/android-ble-device-status-shows-connected-for-some-seconds-even-after-turning-o)

But it still does not satisfy my answer that how can device change its state even when I turn the bluetooth off.

Comment: yea, i faced the same problem in galaxy S8(Nougat) and couple of others with the same android version. i think its a bug in Nougat. I also tested it on Oreo, but its working fine in Oreo. In my case mobile stay connected even if i turn my bluetooth off and it stay connected until i get out of the range of bluetooth device.

Comment: @SalmanNaseem thanks for the input  :), I thought only I am facing this issue .

Comment: Even I have faced the same problem on Moto G  running Marshmallow though it works well on other devices running the same. I don't think it is only on Nougat.

Comment: @Black Thank you for the input :)